# ¿Cómo extraer parte de una cadena según un patrón?

Tags: java, string

Usando el programa Eclipse he creado un *JFrame* simple de ***Java***,  la cual tiene un *JTextField*, un botón, y un *scrollPane* con *textArea*.

Al escribir en el *JTextField* por ejemplo la frase "tengo 8 años" y se presione el botón en el textArea de abajo aparezca "tu edad es 8". También debe funcionar con demás números obviamente.

Necesito que no sólo funcione con la forma "tengo x años", sino también con posibles combinaciones como son "debo decirte que tengo x años", "en realidad tengo x años", y así sucesivamente...

He investigado sobre las cadenas, Strings, substrings, pero no encuentro una forma en la que el programa identifique 
el  patrón "tengo x años" y que posteriormente identifique el número, lo "extraiga" y lo almacene en una variable para poder usarla después.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Entender lo que es una expresión regular (regex) para resolver un caso trivial como este puede parecer demasiado. Sin embargo, es un caso ideal para usar un regex. Teneme paciencia con la explicación, que el código al final se simplifica bastante.

---

En principio, definimos el patrón... la expresión regular:

```
tengo [0-9]+ años
```

- Es el texto literal `"tengo "` al inicio, y `" años"` al final.
- `[0-9]+` coincide con 1 o más dígitos. `[0-9]` coincide con 1 dígito, y el `+` lo repite 1 o más veces.

Y ponemos entre paréntesis lo que nos interesa recuperar luego. Lo que está entre paréntesis se lo llama *grupo*.

```
tengo ([0-9]+) años
```

- `([0-9]+)` es nuestro primer (y único) grupo, para extraer el número.

---

Lo que sigue ahora es el código, casi estándar para extraer el texto que coincide con un regex (ver comentarios en el código):

```
//Las 2 clases necesarias para usar regex
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
//En tu código sería:
//  String cadena=JTextField.getText();
//Pero como ejemplo, lo asignamos a:
String cadena = "Hola, tengo 1 cosa que decir después de 5 años de mentir y es que tengo 33 años de edad";

//Compilamos el regex y el matcher al texto, ignorando mayúsculas/minúsculas (esto es estándar)
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("tengo ([0-9]+) años", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cadena);

//Ahora sí, vemos si coincide el patrón con el texto
if (matcher.find()) {
    //Coincidió => obtener el valor del grupo 1
    String edad = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println("Tu edad es: " + edad);
} else {
    //No coincidió
    System.out.println("No me dijiste tu edad");
}
```

- A tener en cuenta: con el texto que usé, la mayoría de los códigos de esta pregunta fallan.

Resultado:

```
Tu edad es: 33
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/9BUIdQ

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar un [java.util.StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Lo que hace es que te va dando palabra por palabra, hasta que encuentres algo significativo para ti. Por ejemplo:

```
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(texto);
boolean entcontro = false;
while (s.hasMoreTokens() && !enctontro) {
   String t = (String)s.nextToken();
   if (t.toLowerCase().equals("tengo")) {
      /*
        Aquí ya encontraste la etiqueta "tengo" puedes ver si el siguiente
        token es número y lo guardas, y luego el siguiente para ver si
        es "años"..
      */
```

Espero te sirva..
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener claro el patrón que vas a usar, en este caso el patrón es:

***sentencia*** **'X'** *años* ***sentencia***

si sabes que **'X'** es un número entonces puedes hacer un método que te obtenga el número contenido en tu cadena:

```
String cadena = "hola soy juan y tengo 8 años";

public String buscarNumero(String cadena){

    Strign numero = "";
    char[] arreglo = cadena.toCharArray();
    for (char caracter : arreglo){
        if ( Character.isDigit(caracter) )
            numero+=caracter;
    }   

    return numero;
}

System.out.println (buscarNumero(cadena));
```

Comment: pero de ese modo podría también escribir "mi cumpleaños es el 1 de febrero" y el programa cogería ese 1 incluso si no es una edad, por eso necesitaba que cumpla el patrón de que el número se sitúe en medio del "tengo" y "años",

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente logré lo que necesitaba XD **muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda**, esto fue lo que hice:

```
String edad="";
    protected void actionPerformedBtnNewButton(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String cadena=JTextField.getText();    
    String[ ]split=cadena.split("\\s");

    ArrayList<String> arreglo = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){ 
        arreglo.add(split[i]);
    }
     if(arreglo.contains("tengo")) {
        if(arreglo.contains("años")) {
          if(arreglo.indexOf("tengo")<arreglo.indexOf("años"));

          edad=arreglo.get(arreglo.indexOf("tengo")+1);
          txtRespuesta.append("La edad es "+edad);

          }
         }
       }
```

Como ven cumple con el patrón tengo x años, sin importar si esta frase está al inicio o al final, ya que lo que importa es que el elemento "tengo" esté posicionado antes que "años", así que se puede ingresar "debo decirte que tengo x años" y seguirá funcionando a la perfección.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui te dejo un codigo funcional:

```
public int buscarEdad(String cadena){

cadena = "hola soy juan y tengo 8 años y naci el 20 de febrero de 2007";
int edad = 0;
char [] caracteres = cadena.toCharArray();


for(int i= cadena.indexOf("años")-1; i>0; i--){ //empieza el analisis desde la palabra años hacia atras

    if(Character.isDigit(caracteres[i])){ //Revisando que realmente el caracter seleccionado sea un numero
        edad = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(caracteres, i-1, 2).trim()); //toma el numero de la posicion actual y el anterior pero si este es un espacio en blanco lo elimina
        System.out.println("edad:"+edad); //mostrando resultado
        break;
    }
}

return edad;
 }
```

Comment: wow, es muy preciso y creo que lo implementaré al código. Aunque debo decir que hay un detalle con eso, y es que la cadena podría decir "he trabajado en esta empresa durante 4 años", en ese caso el programa tomaría ese 4 como una edad. Entonces se me ocurre si hay alguna forma de hacer primero ese análisis de "años" hacia atrás y después de eso otro análisis pero desde "tengo" hacia adelante, y recolectar el entero que se encuentra en el medio, de ese modo ya no habría confusión. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta igualmente.

Comment: Es interesante pero ya de aquí es solo ser creativo para mejorar el algoritmo. Aquí es donde viene tu magia.